# DMD (D Compiler) home folder location

Tags: linux, path

I installed DMD (the official compiler of the D programming language) in Fedora via the .RPM package I downloaded from the official website. Well, all of this works, the dmd executable is in the PATH variable.
Anyway, I want to know where the home folder of the d compiler is, I know that the executable is at `/usr/bin/`, but I want to locate the folder the executable was copied to `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: *Users* have home directories, binary executables don't. Do you mean the *working directory*?

Comment: Well I mean the directory where dmd executable was copied to /usr/bin. There has to be a directory, where all the other stuff of the program is stored.

Comment: The directory where the executable was copied from depends on the method of installation. Maybe a temporary directory or an on-the-fly extraction from the rpm package. But that's a rather useless piece of information. The files belonging to the compiler can probably be found in `/usr/share/dmc, /usr/lib/i386-linux…, /usr/lib/x86_64…, /usr/include/dmd`. Just check the contents of the rpm package to confirm the exact locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the files part of the compiler package is given by `rpm -ql package-for-DMD`, or (if you are too lazy to look it up) `rpm -qlf /usr/bin/ldc`  (if the compiler is called `ldc`).

Note that there is an official package for D available for Fedora, and has for some time as `ldc`. It is not advisable to go installing third party packages, unless you ***really*** know what you are doing. And if you do know what you are doing, you don't do it ;-)

Note that on Linux, files are stored by *function*, not by origin package. I.e., executables go in `/usr/bin`, libraries somewhere under `/usr/lib`, documentation under `/usr/share/doc` and manuals under `/usr/share/man`. See the [File Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (somewhat out of date, but gives the general view) and Fedora's [packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines) for the gory details for the distribution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and how can I look up the location of the files if I installed dmd through pacman (arch linux) ?

Comment: @YannikK., you could try `which ldc` (if the compiler is called that). Presumably `pacman` has a way to interrogate it's databases about installed packages, but I don't know Arch. Check their fora.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured out the command `pacman -Ql PACKAGE_NAME`.